# Directory.GetFiles does not work as expected

Tags: c#-4.0

```
string[] list = Directory.GetFiles("c:\\", "One Two Three - User.xml")
```

This code does not returns me array, but I have three directories with this file. Any ideas how to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the variation of this method that takes a `SearchOption`, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316.aspx).  It seems that you're after a recursive direction search, and the SearchOption enumeration allows you to specify this.

Answer (score 1):

`Directory.GetFiles` does not traverse subdirs in this way... so only file on C:\ is returned!!
If you need to search this pattern in a dir and in its subdirs you have to scan (recursively) all subdirs and then current dir. In every step you add files to a global variable (`string[] files`).
I think this [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/07wt70x2.aspx) can be useful...
Or you can use `Directory.GetFiles(path, pattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories);`